# Firebase Function onRequest - Check HTTP method is GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing the following cloud function

```
exports.getRandomInteger = functions
  .region(process.env.REGION)
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        validateHttpMethod(req, "GET");

        const authToken = getIdTokenFromRequest(req);

        await verifyIdToken(authToken);

        const {
          lowerLimit,
          upperLimit,
        } = validateGetRandomIntegerParams(req.query);

        const randomInteger = Math.floor(
          Math.random() * (upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1)
        ) + lowerLimit;

        res.status(200).send(randomInteger.toString());
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof functions.https.HttpsError) {
          throw err;
        }

        // An unknown error has occurred
        functions.logger.error(err);

        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          "unknown",
          "Unexpected error.",
          {
            status: "error",
            code: err.code ?? "unknown",
            message: err.message ??
              "Couldn't get random integer. Please, try again later.",
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
```

Inside my `validateHttpMethod(req, "GET")` function I am throwing a `functions.HttpsError` if the request method is not equal to "GET", like this:

```
throw functions.https.HttpsError(
  "invalid-argument",
  "Invalid HTTP method.",
  {
    status: "error",
    code: "http/invalid-method",
    message: "The provided HTTP method is not valid.",
  }
);
```

Is this OK? Should I use "invalid-argument"? Or should I throw the error like this?

```
return res.status(405).send("HTTP method must be GET");
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is:

```js
return res.status(405).send("Method not allowed");
```

`functions.https.HttpsError` are for callable functions, not `onRequest`.